# Designing HTML form in such a way that all textboxes end at the same point

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I want to design an HTML form containing lengthy textboxes and all of them should end at the same point.

The textboxes should start immediately after the question . Below is the image for reference.

[image: HTML Page]

Could you provide the HTML markup for the same.

Here is the markup :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <table class="general" border="0" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <td class="tableBody1" colspan="2"> <strong>Implementation Licensee Information</strong> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bodyText1LIC"> Name and Title&nbsp; </td>
            <td valign="top" class="tableBody1">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPurchasingAgentName" runat="server" MaxLength="255" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator EnableClientScript="False" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPurchasingAgentName" ID="rfvPurchasingAgentName" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Purchasing Agent Name Required" Text="&lt;img src='../images/errorIcon.png' alt='Error Icon'  tabindex='-1' /&gt;" /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bodyText1LIC"> Company Name and Division&nbsp; </td>
            <td valign="top" class="tableBody1">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPurchasingAgentMailingAddress" runat="server" MaxLength="255" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator EnableClientScript="False" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPurchasingAgentMailingAddress" ID="rfvPurchasingAgentMailingAddress" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="PurchasingAgent Mailing address Required" Text="&lt;img src='../images/errorIcon.png' alt='Error Icon'  tabindex='-1' /&gt;" /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bodyText1LIC"> Complete Mailing Address&nbsp; </td>
            <td valign="top" class="tableBody1">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPAPCI_WebAddress" runat="server" MaxLength="255" /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bodyText1LIC"> Direct Telephone No.&nbsp; </td>
            <td valign="top" class="tableBody1">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" MaxLength="255" /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bodyText1LIC"> Email Address&nbsp; </td>
            <td valign="top" class="tableBody1">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" MaxLength="255" /> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nope we don't, just try something by your own first, and we can help you then.

Comment: Show what you have done so far

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Show us some love and give us the code so we can help you :)

Comment: how much do you pay for a direct answer to your direct question? (and without any effort from your side)

Comment: Sorry folks! Forgot to attach the code initially.

Comment: Guys, Apologies for not posting the code initially. I've posted the code now. Request you to reopen the question and suggest me your answers. I am new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/rizalishan/rdvoumkf/1/

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"> This div is as big as it's content</div>
    <div id="right"><input type="text" style="width:100%" /></div>
</div>

#left {
background: #aaa;
float: left}

#right {
background: cyan;
overflow: hidden}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use a table and do not give any border to the table. Eventually you can add css to the table also. Do not give any border to the table.